# Expression Blend Include Code Check Box

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, expression-blend, ironruby

I'm new to WPF and i'm using Expression Blend 4 to create a new WPF application. 
I want to create a bunch of windows and write the back-end code using IronRuby. But while creating a new document or application i don't want to generate the code-behind C# file for the new document. 
 But the include code check box doesn't appear while i choose the "Add new Item" from the File menu. Is there any other way to do this?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There is no checkbox you can use in Expression Blend to turn of the codebehind files. But there is another way that might be of help. You can create custom Project Templates and Item Templates and place them in a specific location so Expression Blend can find them.

The exact details on how to do this can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/unnir/archive/2010/09/17/project-and-item-template-support-in-expression-blend.aspx).